# Ratpack: Response not sent when request body greater than 1 MB

Tags: java, netty, nio, ratpack

I am unable to receive any response if request body size exceeds 1MB.

I reduced maxContentLength to 10KB and then tried sending data grater than 10KB. I am getting error response saying request body is greater than 10KB. (expected behaviour)

But when I set maxContentLength to 1MB or leave default value, I don't get any response at all.